# Outlook changes link url on open

Tags: html, microsoft-outlook-2003

We send and email from our silverlight application with a link like this:

```
http://localhost/invoiceprocessingmfgpro/default.aspx#InkoopFactuur?id=14
```

This is default silverlight behaviour and works on multiple servers with most email clients

when this link is opened in IE9 directly from outlook 2003 
the url opened by IE9 is suddenly changed to:

```
http://localhost/invoiceprocessingmfgpro/default.aspx?id=14#InkoopFactuur
```

it seems to swap the *?id=14* with the *#InkoopFactuur* which off course doesn't work

When we open the html email source in outlook the correct link is displayed.

Copying the link also works.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you copy the html source for the link here verbatim? To rule out that the html may be `<a href="http://localhost/invoiceprocessingmfgpro/default.aspx?id=14#InkoopFactuur>http://localhost/invoiceprocessingmfgpro/default.aspx#InkoopFactuur?id=14</a>`.

Comment: You can rule this out, we've already checked this, the link text = "Open Inkoopfactuur"